# How do I return nothing from a subroutine?

Tags: perl

I want to validate a condition before doing the next step, but only raise a warning and skip the current value instead of die-ing.

How do I rewrite validate_me() subroutine without returning any value?

**(Update)** please note that the following code works as expected, it just that I want something else instead of returning 1 or 0 from validate_me() that still allow the code to behave the same.

```
foreach my $file ( @files ) {
    validate_me($foo, $bar, $baz) or next;
    do_something();
}  

sub validate_me {
    my ($foo, $bar) = @_;

    if ( $foo > $bar ) {
        carp("Something goes awol");
        return 0;
    }

    if ( $bar != $baz ) {
        carp("Odd");
        return 0;
    }

    return 1; # success
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to signal whether or not your validation routine was successful the standard way?  You could probably return undef for false, or definitely an empty string; you can return 2 or 100 or -1 or something weird like 0E0 which is zero but not false for true.  But why not do it the sane way - as in your current code?

Comment: I'm infected by Paul Fenwick's topic "the art of a Klingon programming" which in general it is always better to die/warn from a subroutine rather than returning a value to check.

Maybe that's just not the appropriate technique in my context here.

Comment: Your subroutine IS warning, when it returns 0. You say you don't want it to die (it doesn't) you don't want a return value, but removing the return statements would break the code => **What do you want**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

> I want something else instead of returning 1 or 0 from validate_me() that still allow the code to behave the same.

Is this what you mean? See [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

```
my @files = qw( a b c d e f );

FILES:
foreach my $file ( @files ) {
    eval { validate_me($file) };
    if (my $ex = $@) {
        warn "'$file' failed validation: $ex";
        next FILES;
    }
    print "$file passed\n";
}

sub validate_me {
    my ($file) = @_;
    die "Invalid filename\n" if 0.5 > rand;
    return; # explicitly return nothing
}
```

Now, the sane thing to do would be to refactor `validate_me` into its components:

```
for my $file ( @files ) {
    if ( is_something_gone_awol($file, $mile) ) {
        warn "Something has gone awol: '$file' and '$mile'\n";
    }
    elsif ( is_something_odd($file, $smile) ) {
        warn "Something is odd: '$file' and '$smile'\n";
    }
    else {
        do_something($file);
    }
}

sub is_something_gone_awol {
    my ($foo, $bar) = 0;
    return $foo gt $bar;
}

sub is_something_odd {
    my ($bar, $baz) = @_;
    return $bar ne $baz;
}
```

Comment: I am :) may be I did not express my question clearly. Your solution is still returning 1 from validate_me(), whilst what I'm trying to achieve is to have the code behaves the same as per my example but without checking the return value from validate_me().

Comment: Incidentally, returning undef without die/eval here would be the same.

Answer (score 10):

Check the documentation for [return](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html). If you want to return nothing, don't give return an argument:

```
 return;
```

Comment: I knew that, but how do I rewrite my code snippet above without validate_me() returning 1 or 0?

Comment: Well, where you have return, use the line of code I just gave you.

Comment: @brian: blindly replacing all the lines into "return", including "return 1" in the end will cause the code to break of course?

Comment: If you would like be more verbose you can explicitly write return (); to say: "Really just return nothing".

Comment: @est: I don't know what you are afraid of. In the spot in the code where you want to return nothing, you have your answer. I think you are making this too tough on yourself.

Answer (score 2):

First, there's no reason to use a label in your loop, a `next;` by itself will automatically do the next iteration of the enclosing loop.

As to your question, I'm a little confused about what you're trying to accomplish. Your code as written will return zero, which is a false value, from `validate_me` if any of your tests fail, and that should cause the next iteration of the loop. There's nothing in `validate_me` that would cause anything to die.

Comment: I don't want it to die, just raise warning.

Comment: One of Damian's better ideas from PBP is to label any loop you are going to jump around in with next / last / repeat.  I think this is a good idea, plus you get documentation for the loop and every exit point for free.

Comment: @est, NOTHING in the code you posted would cause anything to die. `carp` emits a warning. Nothing else could cause a fatal error. Try updating your question to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: There's plenty of reason to label a loop. I do it even in not-nested loops to signal what I'm iterating through.

Answer (score 1):

`return;` will just end the function, no questions asked.

But in case you're wondering, you can also return values by using pointers/references passed into your function as parameters.

```
void foo(int input, outStruct *output) {
...
output = new outStruct(...); //for example;
return;
};
```

**EDIT**
I'm a moron, who can't read tags/code.  The example is in C/C++, not Perl.
OOps.

Comment: Did you miss the **[perl]** tag?

Comment: His point is still valid, even if the example is in the wrong language -- a function can update the contents of references that are passed in as arguments, and so pass values back to the caller that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can <strike>`return undef` or</strike> just `return`.

Comment: The two are different. You need to choose one.

Comment: Never return undef. That gives you a list of one item, which is almost never what you want.

Comment: And the difference will show up if you do `@a = validate_me()`  (or, in a common source of bugs with CGI::param, something like `%a = ( 'valid' => validate_me(), ... )`

Comment: @brian d foy: nonsense.  that is quite often what you want, unless your subroutine has some special meaning in list context.  If the normal use is scalar context, much better to return undef even in list context.

Comment: Consider "`my $foo = do { return undef }; say 'false' unless $foo` ==> false;" and "`my @foo = do { return undef }; say 'true' if @foo` ==> 'true'".  This is a confusing API.  I would agree with brian and say to never "return undef".

Comment: I must second brian here too to never return undef. I had been beaten with it several times in the past when my subroutine returns undef in list context.

Comment: In scalar context, there is no difference between `return undef` and `return`. In list context, `return undef` will return a true value. So there is no downside to *never* returning undef explicitly.

Comment: I will never `return undef` again.

Comment: There most certainly is a downside.  If a sub returns some scalar on success, it shouldn't make an exception and return nothing on failure.  Among other cases, you get bugs where people are surprised by $foo in `$foo = bar()` being different than $foo{'bar'} in `%foo = ( 'bar' => bar(), 'baz' => baz() );` (not to mention $foo{'baz'} disappearing).

Comment: I'm guessing jrockway meant eval, not do, there.  And his point seems addressed to a subroutine that is expected to return a list, where I would agree that return undef would be wrong.  But that's a very different case than a subroutine that is expected to return a scalar.

Comment: Ah yes.  I always assume `do` works like `(sub { ... })->()`, but of course it does not.

Comment: You can still return a false scalar, rather than undef. e.g. one might return the result of the spaceship operator or a boolean expression: `return $a < $b;` (which would resolve ysth's example of stuffing return values into a hash). I just wouldn't ever explicitly return **undef**.

Comment: another discussion of this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435122/whats-the-difference-between-return-and-return-undef-in-perl