# What's the difference between return; and return undef; in Perl

Tags: perl

Is there a difference between a subroutine that does

```
return;
```

and one that does?

```
return undef;
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`return;` will return an empty list in list context but `undef` in scalar context.  `return undef;` will always return a single value `undef` even in list context.

In general, it's usually not a good idea to `return undef;` from a subroutine normally used in list context:

```
sub foo { return undef }
if ( my @x = foo() ) {
    print "oops, we think we got a result";
}
```

In general, it's usually not a good idea to `return;` from a subroutine normally used in scalar context, because it won't behave as the user expects in list context:

```
sub foo { return }
%x = ( 'foo' => foo(), 'bar' => 'baz' );
if ( ! exists $x{'bar'} ) {
    print "oops, bar became a value, not a key";
}
```

Both of these errors happen quite a bit in practice, the latter more so, perhaps because subs that are expected to return a scalar are more common.  And if it's expected to return a scalar, it had better return a scalar.

Comment: In your second example I'd say the fault wasn't the definition of foo, but having a sub on the right hand side of a fat comma. IMHO that is fragile programming style.

Comment: @nslntmnx: I'm not clear on what the fat comma has to do with it or what you would do instead.  Can you explain?

Comment: This all stems from the fact that fat comma does *NOT* force scalar context on right hand side. IMHO in the second example the definition of sub foo is perfect.  The failure was caused by the questionable coding style of having a sub call on the right hand side of a fat comma. Having a sub call on the right hand side ( as you have shown ) can lead to the key/pairs being corrupted, hence fragile coding style.

Comment: Much safer style to do in two steps 1) grab the return values of sub foo into a scalar variable 2) assign that scalar to value of key 'foo'.  Formally speaking, IMHO the second example isn't a valid test of the sub foo, because the call to sub foo wouldn't be used because of that fragile nature. Typically having a function call on right hand side of comma would be rejected in a formal code review at places I have worked at.

Comment: The answer by @friedo has simple robust code examples that show the sub foo returns expected values in both scalar and list context.  But sub bar fails to return empty list in scalar context.

Comment: @nslntmnx I guess I would agree with you, if you allow subs that have unexpected returns; my argument is that it is ridiculous to allow that in the first place.  The vast majority of subs do something that by nature would either return a scalar or return a list, and that's what they should *consistently* do.

Comment: Agree with @nslntmnx. The problem is that this bug might happen even without without an explicit return; consider `sub foo { }` or even `sub foo { die; }; %x = ( 'foo' => eval { foo() } ...`. Since the return value of a sub is that of the last statement, unless you can guarantee this will never return an undef (including any library calls you might be using), never use a function after a fat comma (or use `'foo' => scalar foo()`).

Comment: @geira: never do implicit returns

Comment: As shown in my example, "die" is an implicit return. Saying no function should ever die (including segfaulting C libraries) is not very realistic.

Comment: @geira: I was addressing your 'return value of a sub is that of that last statement'; that's not something that should ever happen in professionally written code.  with respect to your other points, I can only reiterate that the caller of a function that can naturally be expected to return a scalar should be able to expect that it returns a scalar.  the eval is a red herring; there, it's not the caller of the function that needs to take thought, it's the code that calls eval (and indeed you should expect that eval may return an empty list)

Answer (score 23):

Given

```
sub foo { return; }
sub bar { return undef; }
```

In scalar context, they behave the same.

```
my $foo = foo();   # $foo is undef
my $bar = bar();   # $bar is undef
```

In list context, they behave differently

```
my @foo = foo();   # @foo is ()  (an empty list)
my @bar = bar();   # @bar is ( undef )  (a one-element list)
```

Note that a one-element list is a true value in boolean context, even though the only element is `undef`.

In general, it's usually not a good idea to `return undef;` from a subroutine, because of how it behaves in context.

Comment: This is why "Perl Best Practices" (and `Perl::Critic`) suggest not using `return undef`.

Comment: @hillu: and it is same reason why sometime it is good idea to use it. For example function is supposed to return logical (boolean) answer and you wish to use it another function call `foo(1, bar(), 2)`. If `bar` would written with `return;` you will be surprised ;-)

Comment: One of the more that a few things that PBP gets *correct*

Answer (score 2):

I think I still agree with PBP though.

1) You should avoid nesting function calls:

```
my $result = bar();
foo(1, $result, 2);
```

2) You should always be explicit (when doing "complicated" things):

```
foo(1, scalar bar(), 2);
```

Comment: 1) It's not just nesting function calls.  2) Yes, from the caller's perspective that would be a good thing.  From the callee's perspective it shouldn't be counted on.

Comment: 1) more examples then?

anyway, I believe you would end up with erratic results more often with 
    $ perl -wle 'sub get_values { return undef; }; my @values = get_values; print scalar @values;'
    1

If you want to be more explicit and proper, there is always Contextual::Return http://p3rl.org/Contextual::Return

Comment: your `get_values` is intended for use in list context, and as such should _not_ `return undef`.  But if you had a `get_value` function that returned a scalar, it should _always_ return a scalar, never an empty list, so it would use `return undef`.  See ysth's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The book "Perl Best Practices" recommends the use of `return;` instead of `return undef;` because the latter would return a one-element list in list context (the other answers already mention this). This would be a "nasty bug" according to the book.

However, I think returning nothing can actually cause serious bugs (probably difficult to find), whereas calling a boolean function in list context seems rather simple to debug.

So I *always* return *something* (that evaluates to) false in my boolean functions (usually 0 for false and 1 for true).
(Yes, this would also return a one-element list in list context - so the comment in the book is technically right -, but then the actual error would be calling the boolean function in list context.)

To be clear, I still recommend the book. It offers a lot of good advice.
And I am referring to Chapter 9 (Subroutines), page 199/200 ("Use a bare return to return failure.") in the book "Perl Best Practices" by Damian Conway (O'Reilly Media, Inc.), ISBN 978-0-596-00173-5. Not sure if there's another/newer edition.

Side note:
Perl seems to return an empty string when negating something. `my $foo = 5; return !$foo;` returns `q()`.

Comment: `!$foo` is the empty string because Perl uses 1 for true and the empty string for false.  Because of the `!`, you are in a boolean context.

Comment: No, ´!5´ is the canonical false value, which is "" in string context and 0 in numeric context.