# Returning error messages from perl subroutines

Tags: perl

Is this a good way of returning an error messages from a subroutine in perl?

```
sub some_subroutine{
    # do something
    $something = 14;

    if(1 == 2){
        $_ = "This should not be happening!";
        return undef;
    }
    return $something;
}

my $ret=some_subroutine();
print "ERROR: $_" unless(defined $ret);
```

The code runs OK (in a parallel world, where `1 == 2`), but using `$_` to return the error message is a good way? I didn't found any documentation regarding the usage of `$_` for this kind of purposes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`$_` is not a good mechanism as so many other things use and set it.

You could set some other global variable, like $Error, but the best way is to throw an exception.  Then the user doesn't have to always check, and forget, it just happens.  In Perl, exceptions are generated with  "[die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html)".  die will take a string or an object.  There's a number of modules to make throwing exceptions easier including [Exception::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exception::Class), [Exception::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exception::Simple), [Ouch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Ouch) and [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie).

You can catch the exception with [eval {}](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), but there are [a number of problems with that](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny#BACKGROUND) so you should use something like [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny).

Comment: do you not find it semantically valuable to return some error/undefined state when the error is not "exceptional?"  If you are expecting, say, that a file may not be there, does it not make more sense semantically to return an error state rather than throw an exception?  It's a small point, I know...

Comment: @SoloBold Don't get too wound up in the exact meaning of "exception". If the subroutine can't do its job, it's an exceptional case. If it means the caller cannot expect a normal return value, it's an exceptional case. If you write a subroutine that checks for the existence of a file it's not exceptional if it's not there.  If you write a routine that reads and parses a file, it should throw an exception if the file is not there.

Comment: ...If the larger system is ok with that file missing, you can put a wrapper around that which checks for the existence of the file and returns and empty structure if not.  Finally, programmers will forget to write error handling code, but you have to deliberately ignore an exception.  It is optimized for laziness.

Answer (score 8):

It's not unknown to use a global variable to hold the error message. For example, built-in function use `$!`, and DBI uses `$DBI::errstr`. But then you inherit all the problems of using global variables. Signal handlers need to localise them, destructors can clobber them, multi-threading issues, etc.

It seems to me that throwing an exception (e.g. using `die`) is a more common choice.

Whatever you do, don't use `$_`. It is often aliased to something, so using it could have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do to make this slightly better is to simply `return;` on error/undefined result.  There are contexts where `return undef;` can be evaluated as `true`.  You might check out [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735)'s chapter on error handling as it covers this and has other good pointers.

For example, if:

```
my $ret=some_subroutine();
print "ERROR: $_" unless(defined $ret);
```

becomes

```
my @ret=some_subroutine();         # oops!
print "ERROR: $_" unless(defined $ret);
```

You have a weird bug (not catching the error) that may be hard to track down, whereas if you `return;` from `some_subroutine` you get:

```
my @ret=some_subroutine();         # oops!
print "ERROR: $_" unless($ret);    # but error is still caught
```

Furthermore, in the case of a function that should return a list:

```
my @ret=some_other_subroutine();    # OK
print "ERROR: $_" unless($ret);     # error will be caught if you "return;"

# ... but later ...

my $ret=some_other_subroutine();    # oops!
print "ERROR: $_" unless($ret);     # if you "return;" $ret will equal 0
                                    # (the length of the returned list)
                                    # and the error will be caught
```

So, while there are other patterns for returning error/undefined status from a function, always using `return;` allows the use of one pattern for nearly all functions, both in returning the appropriate value and when it comes time to check for error status.

Comment: This is an example of bad advice in PBP.  If a subroutine normally returns a scalar, return undef on error, not an empty list.

Comment: That's interesting, but you haven't convinced me.  It seems equally bad to return a one element list `(undef)` if the function is called in list context.  The subroutine may return a scalar, but if you call it from list context you won't get a scalar if I understand correctly.  You can always be sure that !foo() will be true when you `return;` but not if you `return undef;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435122/whats-the-difference-between-return-and-return-undef-in-perl

Comment: But, I mean, definitely convince me if I'm wrong.  I tried to explain better in the answer.

Comment: If a subroutine normally returns a list, then, yes, return an empty list.  The typical error case for `return undef;` (`@x=somesub()`) is likely to be encountered only if the subroutine is normally used in list context; the typical error case for `return;` ( `%x = ( 'sub1' => sub1(), 'sub2' => sub2() )` ) is likely to be encountered only if the subroutine is normally used in scalar context.

Comment: @ysth still not seeing why this is wrong.  The hash example seems like more of a corner case than most uses.

Comment: @ysth  The values are being inserted into the hash before validating them, after all.

Comment: @SoloBold: if code is checking to see if the sub was successful, then there is definitely no problem.  it's only callers who don't check who might have a problem, in either case.  The hash example applies to "named" subroutine parameters too.

Comment: @ysth, I see your point, but I don't see that using `return;` everywhere is bad advice.

Comment: Maybe an explicit case would help?  `sub show_bar { my %args=@_; print "bar: $args{'bar'}\n" } sub get_foo { return; } show_bar( 'foo' => get_foo(), 'bar' => 'barbar' )`  Here get_foo, by name and usage, is clearly supposed to return a scalar, but in an error case it doesn't, resulting in not just an error, but one that isn't directly traceable to the get_foo call.  This happens very commonly to people who use `return;` everywhere.

Comment: No, no, I see that.  I just don't see why this one kind of error is more important to watch for than the two I outlined in the answer, or why using `return;` is bad advice, or indeed any worse advice than using `return undef;` for scalar functions and `return;` in list functions... both require you to code in certain patterns.  IMHO, using `return;` always is more straightforward.  Perhaps we will have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Perhaps we will.  Summary of my argument: my way works if you use scalar functions to get scalars; yours doesn't, choosing instead to guard against trying to get a list from the scalar function and then using that operation itself in scalar context.

Comment: PBP's recommended method "works" in scalar context.  The points about that are valid, but you should also point out that "your" way has problems with another set of common errors - including typos.

Comment: I have yet to see an example of that set of errors that's anything like as common (*for functions that normally return a scalar*)

Comment: Personally, I make typos much more often than I call subroutines inside hash or array declarations ;) Especially given the proximity of `@`, `$`, and `%`.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on what behavior you are expecting to see from your error handler. It is very common in perl to use `die` or `warn` in case a runtime error/warning happens.

Take a look at this tutorial on error handling in perl: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_error_handeling.htm

Answer (score 0):

For a web service, you could write a subroutine for printing custom error responses (40x errors, etc.).