# How to assign array to default if fetchrow_array returns no rows

Tags: arrays, perl

I guess I can divide it into two questions.

1.What if I want to do something below in one single step.

```
if($sth->fetchrow_array is empty /undef){
    @parent = @default;
}
```

I tried something like this but failed.

```
@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array or @default;
## Problem is it assign undef if array1 is undef.

@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array || @default;
##  problem is it assign scalar value to the parent if it's not undef
```

2.Below is the sample code. Why I get scalar value in second output?

```
@default = (2,3,4);

## First output
@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array or @default;
print @parent;

##Second output;
@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array || @default;
print @parent;
```

Comment: if I do 

    `@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array or @default;`   

It retuns undef

If I do

    `@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array || @default;`

it returns array count, not the array.

Comment: `or` and `||` evaluate their LHS operand in scalar context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `fetchrow_array` I suggest that you use `fetchrow_arrayref`, which returns `undef` if there is no more data to be returned

Then you can write

```
@parent = @{ $sth->fetchrow_arrayref || \@default };
```

or, if it's convenient, you could keep the result as a reference with

```
$parent = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref || \@default;
```

Comment: Thank you, Borodin. This is what I did after giving up. But I still wanna know they way to make sure fetchrow_array never give  me row with undef value.

Answer (score 1):

`@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array or @default;` parses as `(@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array) or @default;`, which should give you this warning:

```
Useless use of private array in void context at foo.pl line 123.
```

`@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array || @default;` parses as `@parent = ($sth->fetchrow_array || @default);`, which is better. But `||` puts its left operand in scalar context (because it needs to check it as a boolean value) and it doesn't evaluate its left operand twice. So it ends up being the same as `@parent = scalar($sth->fetchrow_array) || @default;`, which is also not what you want.

You can do the following:

```
@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array;
@parent = @default if !@parent;
```

But there's no good way to do it in one statement.

Comment: The problem here is fetchrow_array does not return undef if no rows rather it returns a row with undef value. So the `@parent = @default if !@parent;` would still not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array  or  @parent = @default;
(@parent = $sth->fetchrow_array) || (@parent = @default);
@parent = @default unless @parent = $sth->fetchrow_array;
```

(this won't quite do what you want if @Shahid Siddique is correct that `fetchrow_array` can return an array with one `undef` element when the query has no results, but that hasn't been my experience)

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong while mocking.
I return undef for fetchrow_array which instead returns a column with undef.
`$mock_sth->mock( 'fetchrow_array', sub {return undef});`

**NOTE that NULL fields are returned as undef in the array returned by fetchrow_array (more about NULL values later).** according to this doc (http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/dbd_odbc_tutorial_part_2.html)

Comment: `return undef` [is usually the wrong way to go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435122) precisely because in list context you would want to return `()` and not `(undef)`

Comment: Rendering NULL database values as `undef` in Perl makes sense, but that is a different "NULL" then the result of a database query with zero rows.