# perl function ignores undef arguments

Tags: perl

I'm passing some arguments to a function, one of which might be undefined.

```
$a = ($config->function(param('a'),'int'));
```

my module contains a function which looks like this:

```
sub function{                    
        my $self = $_[0];           
        my $t = $_[1];              
        my $type = $_[2];           
        print "$self,$t,$type<br/>";
}
```

I've tried with `shift` instead of the `@_` syntax, but there's no change.
The problem is that if `$config->function` is called with an undefined `param('a')` it prints like this:

`MY_FUNC=HASH(0x206e9e0),name,`
it seems that `$t` is being set to the value of what `$type` should be and the `undef` is being ignored completely.

Comment: Wait, `$config` is undef?  How is Perl then resolving the package to find `function()` in, without a blessed reference?

Comment: No, `$config` is defined. `param('a')` is occasionally `undef`. Sorry about that. I've edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CGI `param` method is correctly returning an empty list in the case of an error. This is standard behaviour for Perl subroutines and methods, which return a *false* value in the case of an erorr.

As @mob says, an explicit `return undef` is wrong precisely because it returns a one-element list in list context. This is a *true* value and implies success, which would break a lot of code if it was changed

All you need to do is change your code to extract the parameter separately

```
my $param = param('a');
$config->function($param, 'int'));
```

or if you're *really* keen to put the call in the parameter list then you can write

```
$config->function(scalar param('a'), 'int'));
```

or

```
$config->function(param('a') // undef, 'int'));
```

Comment: Third solution works for me. Didn't know about the `//`, where could I find documentation on that? (googling of course generally fails on non-alphanumeric characters)

Comment: returning an empty list is standard behaviour for subs that return lists; this isn't an error, exactly.  Note that param('a') in the original code could have returned more than one value, creating quite another problem.  CGI seems to return the first 'a' param in scalar context; it's possible EricR may want `(param('a'))[-1]` instead.

Comment: @ysth, He's most likely expecting 0 or 1 parameters, so there's no difference between first (`(param('a'))[0]`) and last (`(param('a'))[-1]`).

Answer (score 4):

`undef` is perfectly valid in a parameter list. I suspect that the problem here is that the `param` function is returning an empty list, rather than `undef`.

```
sub function {
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    print join "/", @_;
}

function(undef,"foo");      #   outputs "/foo"
function((), "foo");        #   outputs "foo"
```

In the argument list to `function`, the  `param` function is evaluated in list context.

```
sub param1 {
    return;     # undef in scalar context, but empty list in list context
}

sub param2 {
    return undef;    # scalar ctx: undef, list ctx: list with one undef elem
}

function(param1(), "foo");    #   param1() -> () ... outputs "foo"
function(param2(), "foo");    #   param2() -> (undef) ... outputs "/foo"
```

A workaround is to make sure that your `param` function is evaluated in scalar context.

```
function(scalar param1(), "foo");    # now outputs "/foo"
```

Note that actually saying `return undef` in your Perl subroutines is [considered by some to be a code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604654/168657).

Comment: In fact, if it ends with `return;`, it _will_ return an empty list rather than `undef` here, I think.

Comment: Unfortuantely for me, the param function is CGI's `param`. If it's code smell, it's their fault.

"If the parameter does not exist at all, then param() will return undef in a scalar context, and the empty list in a list context." (from perldoc)

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. Now to refactor my entire codebase due to `CGI param`. Fun.

Comment: It's not code smell.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435122/whats-the-difference-between-return-and-return-undef-in-perl for another opinion than mob's.

Comment: `param` doesn't "stink". `param` can return any number of values, since a parameter can appear any number of times. e.g., `param('a')` returns `3,4,5` for `?a=3&a=4&a=5`. And as you've discovered, it returns `()` for `?b=7`. This is very appropriate behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

[I started this as a comment but it got too long].

Inside an argument list, arguments are evaluated in list context. Two answers have already noted that, but I think you missed it for all of the other things they were talking about.

Beyond that, `param` has to handle at least three cases, and the interface Lincoln chose, although sometimes annoying, is a good enough way to handle them.

The query parameter `a` does not appear at all:

```
b=1
```

The query parameter `a` appears, but with no value:

```
a=&b=1
```

The query parameter `a` appears with a value:

```
a=1&b=1
```